# ignoring div class using rvest

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying the following to extract a portion of a page whilst ignoring one of the nested fields "ratings". The following syntax are both not successful in extracting what I need. Any suggestions?

```
raw <- read_html(res[[1]])  %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '(//div[@class="results" and not(div[contains(@class, "span4 mobile-span1 ratings")])]') 

raw <- read_html(res[[1]])  %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '(//div[not(contains(@class, "span4 .mobile-span1 .ratings"))]//div[@class="results"])')
```

Comment: Did you try `vignette('selectorgadget', package = 'rvest')`?

Comment: Yes, I did. The reason why I am interested in a method to exclude a particular nested div tag is so that I can extract multiple pages via a loop. The loop gets thrown off because of uneven lengths for particular fields (ie, there is nothing for that field). I cannot use a html_table() because the information is not in a table.

Comment: If you edit with some sample HTML and what you'd like it to match or not match, you're much more likely to get a useful answer. As a general strategy, though, _sometimes_ it's easiest to scrape more than you need with `html_nodes` and then just chop it down to what you want after the fact.

Comment: If the site is (a) not internal and (b) does not have a restrictive ToS or (c) require a login, please post the URL. If it's (b) please don't give R a bad name by using it to break civil law and violate ToS. If it's (a) or (c) please provide some HTML snippet.